# Using a view with a superlayer as a layer mask

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have a view that I want to overlay with a transparent black layer whose edges match the view exactly. The view does not clip its bounds, so subviews may be hanging off.

The obvious solution is the `mask` property of `CALayer`, but the docs say that the mask layer **"must not have a superlayer"** or the behavior is undefined.

I was hoping that using the `presentationLayer` of that view would be an effective workaround, but I don't think I fully understand what presentation layers are, as that property returns `nil`.

Does anyone have tips on how I could mask my transparent black layer to match the shape of the view over which it will be drawn? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a less obvious solution to this that should work better than masking: a blend-mode filter, specifically [source-atop](https://ciechanow.ski/alpha-compositing/#atop). If you add your transparent layer as a sibling of the layers it’s supposed to dim, and assign it the appropriate [CI compositing filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISourceAtopCompositing), it will dim those layers without affecting anything outside of their boundaries. As a bonus, you’ll get correct antialiasing at the edges, unlike the masked-overlay approach.

Here’s an example. For illustrative purposes I made the dimming layer only half the height of the area it covers, but you’d of course want to make it larger.

[image: green and purple squares on a blue background, with a central region of the two squares dimmed]

```
let container = CALayer()
container.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBlue.cgColor
container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

let dimmedRoot = CALayer()
let dimmedLayer1 = CALayer()
dimmedLayer1.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)
dimmedLayer1.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemGreen.cgColor
dimmedLayer1.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.3, 0, 0, 1)

let dimmedLayer2 = CALayer()
dimmedLayer2.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100)
dimmedLayer2.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemPurple.cgColor
dimmedLayer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-0.1, 0, 0, 1)

let dimmingLayer = CALayer()
dimmingLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100)
dimmingLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
dimmingLayer.compositingFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceAtopCompositing")

dimmedRoot.sublayers = [ dimmedLayer1, dimmedLayer2, dimmingLayer ]

container.addSublayer(dimmedRoot)
```

Comment: Hmm.. Clicking the `dimmingLayer` where its frame does *not* intersect any sibling still results in its window receiving a `sendEvent` message. Would you consider this a bug? Presumably, a borderless window should not handle events when transparent pixels are clicked. Maybe you can file a radar?

Comment: CA’s hit testing isn’t aware of compositing filters; it would be complicated and expensive to figure out whether a given set of filters ended up resulting in a transparent pixel. I think you might be able to solve that by making `dimmingLayer` a custom CALayer subclass and overriding the `containsPoint` function to return false.

Comment: Worth noting that I'm still seeing mismatched antialiasing when using the `compositingFilter` approach. At least, when the dimmed view is a super ellipse: https://github.com/aleclarson/react-native-super-ellipse-mask/blob/99aec94dfd19a3d835a1e27e3b6c15a299a8bd54/ios/SuperEllipseMask.m