# CAMetalLayer with texture rendered by CARenderer is not visible?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer, metal

I'm using a `CARenderer` to render another `CALayer` tree into a `CAMetalLayer`, which I hope to use as the `mask` of yet another layer. For testing purposes, I've tried adding the `CAMetalLayer` as a normal sublayer instead of a mask.

The `layer` object below is not visible after adding it to a superlayer that is definitely visible. I've confirmed the `frame` of the layer is not a problem. Here's how I'm making the `CAMetalLayer` and its `CARenderer`.

```
CAMetalLayer *layer = [CAMetalLayer layer];
layer.frame = bounds;
layer.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
//layer.opaque = NO;
//layer.framebufferOnly = NO;

id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = layer.nextDrawable;
_lastDrawable = drawable;

_renderer = [CARenderer rendererWithMTLTexture:drawable.texture options:nil];
_renderer.layer = self.superview.layer;
_renderer.bounds = bounds;
```

By creating a `CIImage` and inspecting it with the debugger, I've confirmed the `CARenderer` is updating the Metal texture.

```
CIImage *img = [CIImage imageWithMTLTexture:_lastDrawable.texture options:nil];
```

But when I set the `superlayer` of the `CAMetalLayer`, it's nowhere to be seen.

```
[self.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Here's how I'm using the `CARenderer`:

```
[_renderer beginFrameAtTime:CACurrentMediaTime() timeStamp:NULL];
[_renderer addUpdateRect:bounds];
[_renderer render];
[_renderer endFrame];
```

That last snippet runs frequently.

---

#### edit 1

I've added a `backgroundColor` and now the `layer` is visible, but its texture is not being rendered inside it.

```
layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellowColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using a Metal layer rather than setting the layer tree as a mask itself? It would make more sense if you were doing custom Metal drawing, but doing a round-trip out of CA seems odd.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon As I understand it, `CALayer` objects don't generate a bitmap on the CPU, so I figured I could reduce CPU usage by masking with the GPU texture instead (if that's even possible).

Comment: I see. It is possible, but I would definitely try the simpler way first. Elaborated a bit in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just setting the original layer as a mask rather than trying to render it to a texture first; you’re sort of duplicating the work that CA would be doing anyway.

If you really need control over when the mask layer tree gets rendered—and again you should definitely try the standard method first—the right way to do this would be to create an [IOSurface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/IOSurface)-[backed MTLTexture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433378-maketexture) rather than using a CAMetalLayer’s drawable, draw into the texture with your CARenderer, set the IOSurface as the contents of a regular CALayer, and use that layer as the mask.

Comment: I did try the standard method first, but it didn't work, presumably because the layer already has a superlayer. In other words, the layer must render normally and also be a mask for another layer. I asked about this previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65962728/using-a-view-with-a-superlayer-as-a-layer-mask

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Then I would try the IOSurface route.